# any way to pass -Usechecksum to msdeploy using msbuild

Tags: msdeploy, tfsbuild, webdeploy

I have a website with lots of files using team build and deploying though web deploy packages.  The problem i am having is that the packages are build from one of the machines from the farm and the time stamp will not always match.  By default with web deploy that means a full site roll and with so many file and the sync across the cluster this is not optimal.

With cmd line deploy i can pass -UseCheckSum and this is solved for manual deployment.  Now i'm trying to use a CI build with auto deploy and passing MSbuild arguments though my build setup.  Is there a way to get this to deploy in the same manner?

Answer (score 6):

You can't do it in your MSBuild, but you can edit the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets file on the build server to apply -UseChecksum.

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13863041/8037

**UPDATE**: MS has added the ability to pass the UseChecksum flag to VS 2013. To do this, add the following property to the .pubxml file:

```
<MSDeployUseChecksum>true</MSDeployUseChecksum>
```

Further information can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/30/web-publishing-updates-for-app-offline-and-usechecksum.aspx

Comment: NOTE TO MODS: Why did you delete my previous answer? It specifically answered the question. Color me confused.

Answer (score 0):

If, by "MSBuild" you mean the Web Publishing Pipeline, then the answer is no. The `MSDeploy` msbuild task supports a `UseChecksum` property, but the WPP targets provide no mechanism through which you can set it. This is also true of a number of other features (like stored credentials).