# Using MSDeploy/Web Deploy as Publish method in Visual Studio with multiple users

Tags: visual-studio, webdeploy

Is it possible to use web deploy from multiple developer PC's?

When we try to do so it seems we need to re-publish everything when someone else wants to do a deploy.

Are we doing something wrong, is there a way around this, or what would be a recommended approach in our scenario?

I'm aware that deploying from a central location is a better founded solution, but unfortunately this is not an option at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Visual Studio, no. The current build scripts don't have a way of providing the necessary flag to MSDeploy.

If you are using the generated `cmd` file from a package to perform the deployment you can append `-useChecksum` to your command line and it will use checksum comparisons rather than the last modified date.

Comment: That's it, great, thanks!

I'm still finding my way around the msdeploy and webdeploy ecosystem. Can you point me to any documentation where this is explained?

Comment: OK nevermind about the question for documentation, it's right here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Just noting that using checksum can now be configured to be used within Visual Studio, as of version 2013. More info at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/30/web-publishing-updates-for-app-offline-and-usechecksum.aspx

Answer (score 17):

You can't do it from your project, but it's simple to edit the Visual Studio MSBuild scripts to turn it on (for all web deploys). Here's how:

1. Open `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets`
2. Find the `MSDeployPublish` target
3. Inside that task, find the call to the `VSMSDeploy` task (line 4376 or so)
4. Add the `UseChecksum="true"` attribute to the `VSMSDeploy` task call

You can also do this for the deploy preview by following the same steps, but look for the MSDeployFilePreview target in step 2 rather than the MSDeployPublish task.

Make sure to restart VS after you make the changes to ensure they're properly picked up.

**UPDATE**: MS has added the ability to pass the UseChecksum flag to VS 2013. To do this, add the following property to the .pubxml file:

```
<MSDeployUseChecksum>true</MSDeployUseChecksum>
```

Further information can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/30/web-publishing-updates-for-app-offline-and-usechecksum.aspx)