# Team Foundation Service, Publishing to Staging/Production

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-deployment, azure-devops

I've been looking at publishing solutions for TFS from Visual studio 2012 and I'm trying to find the most ideal way to perform this job.

Originally I've done this via FTP and publish packages, but this can suffer from long upload times depending on the size of the project. I've also installed VS2012 on one of the staging servers before and by performing a get latest and then a local publish from the server itself is normally quite quick, but I don't like having to install this on servers.

An ideal solution would be to only upload differences from the latest publish, this would improve the upload time and would almost be like a remote "Get Latest". Is this possible, or is there an alternative that might work for me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already publishing from TFS via build definitions, Web deploy has several settings for synchornizing content such that only the latest changes are deployed, rather than copying everything each time.

[If needed, here's a guide to get you started with Web Deploy from Vishal Joshi](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/11/team-build-web-deployment-web-deploy-vs.html#!/2010/11/team-build-web-deployment-web-deploy-vs.html)

[Here's a link to Web Deploy operation settings.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28WS.10%29.aspx)  In particular, the 
'sync' verb and 'dest' and 'UseCheckSum' settings may allow the desired level of control.

I had a tough time gauging if I understood your problem correctly, hope this helps.

Comment: Although your answer was very useful and helped me understand web publishing more, I found that the answer here was exactly what I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13863041/529544